# Use geolocation plugin in october cms

Tags: geolocation, octobercms, octobercms-plugins, octobercms-backend

I have try to install geolocation plugin in october cms

but i am getting error[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uaxzP.png)

Comment: What is your php version?

Comment: 7.0.21 , can you please guide me how can i use plugin in my project. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You posted that your version is PHP 7.0.2 but it supports the array as constant

I guess, PHP version below 5.6 is not supporting this.

may be you are having issue related to version.
reference : https://3v4l.org/T44gG

may be, you did check command line version (CLI version) of php using

> php --version

so at there it may be showing you 7.0 but in your apache config you may still using old version.

to confirm that you are also using PHP 7.0 in Apache you can create small php file with below code.

```
<?php
    phpinfo();
```

then check what version is there.

if its also showing 7.0 then i don't know its something else.

but if its shows 5.x some things then you need to update your apache config

I assume you are on linux machine so, all commands are related to linux op. system

> install apache php 7.0 mod (mod = module)

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php7.0
```

> now enable php 7 module before that disable old php5 mod, **(sudo a2dismod php5)**

```
sudo a2enmod php7.0
```

let me know if its works or not.